# setting div height to full display height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

this is all over the stackoverflow,but it doesn't work for me.
using `twitter bootstrap 3`, i need to set the `jumbotron` class div to full display height.

this is my test site:
http://test.ulkas.eu/

i read i shall include

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

but it still doesn't work. maybe i got some syntax error somewhere?

Comment: Also add height:100% to your body as well as to jumbotron class

Comment: could you put it as answer? it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply 100% height property to inner divisions you need to mention the same property to all the parent divs. So add

```
body{height: 100%;min-height:100%;padding-top:50px;}

.jumbotron{height:100%;}
```

to your body as well as to jumbortron class

Answer (score 0):

The height of your html / body will always only be the height of your content - those tags behave slightly different to standard div / block tags. To get something to be truly 100% high your best bet is to remove it from the standard flow of the page using position: absolute / fixed, then set your div to be 100% high. Something like this:

```
.fullheight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I think it's always worth setting a z-index on anything I position outside the normal page flow, allows you to control which parts appear on top of others.